# Shuffling Parameters

Tags: python

I'm a begginer in Python, and I was reading a book.

So this is a funcion that imitates **range()**

```
def interval(start, stop=None, step=1):
    'Imitates range() for step > 0'
    if stop is None: 
        start, stop = 0, start      # How is this evaluated?
    result = []
    i = start 
    while i < stop:
        result.append(i)
        i += step
    return result
```

My question here is: How is evaluated the:

`start, stop = 0, start` part?

Because I understand that the parameters should evaluate like this:

`5, stop = 0, 5`  (I know I'm wrong but I need you to tell me how is this part evaluated)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences. This is called tuple or sequence unpacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form

```
x, y = a, b
```

is a multiple assignment which is [well (but obtusely) documented](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). The simple example I gave would be equivalent to

```
x = a
y = b
```

or in the case of your example `start, stop = 0, start`

```
stop = start
start = 0
```

Notice how I reordered the assignments; this is one advantage of multiple assignment. In this case you'd have to add a temporary variable if you wanted the same effect:

```
temp = start
start = 0
stop = temp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call `interval( 10 )`, then `start = 0` and `stop = 10`. When `interval( 5, 10 )` is called, then `start = 5` and `stop = 10`.

`start, stop = 0, start` is equivalent to `stop = start; start = 0`.

Comment: why is equivalent? I don't see where stop takes the value of start

Comment: Python expand it. You can use `dis` module and check it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called tuple unpacking.

```
In [24]: x,y = 0,1

In [25]: print(x)
0

In [26]: print(y)
1
```

You can do this for any sequence.  In the above, you are in-line specifying a tuple with (0,1).  You can also unpack, say, an iterable:

```
In [28]: a,b,c = range(3)

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 0

In [30]: b
Out[30]: 1

In [31]: c
Out[31]: 2
```

but you have to make sure that the number of arguments you provide to unpack makes sense.

```
In [32]: a,b = range(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ben/<ipython-input-32-ec703b8346af> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b = range(3)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

In [33]: a,b,c,d = range(3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ben/<ipython-input-33-16ef42f82877> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b,c,d = range(3)

ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

Note that (and this is the part that seems to be confusing you) the right side is evaluated *before* the left side.  This allows for the common idiom:

```
In [34]: x = 0

In [35]: y = 1

In [36]: x,y = y,x
```

Answer (score 1):

a, b = c, d is equivalent to a = c and b = d